# Is it possible to edit the text within a photo that I already posted on Facebook?

Tags: facebook

Is it possible to edit the text within  a photo that I already posted on Facebook a week ago? I have a typing error in the text WITHIN the respective photo and I would like to correct it.

Answer (score 2):

Facebook allows you only to rotate the photo that you have already uploaded but not possible to edit the content within image.

This is because for editing the image facebook should have integrate the photo editing tool in their website but it is not available with face. So, it is not possible to edit the image in facebook

Hope this helps!